# NTFS Master File Table Parser

Tags: python, file-system

I have written a Python program to parse the Master File Table located by `//?/X:/$MFT`.

Of course trying to open it normally will result in `PermissionDenied`. I got around this by `open(f"//?/{drive}:", "rb")`, and get the starting cluster of $MFT and read the first 1024 bytes starting at 4096 * cluster count.

I wrote this program to parse all file records in $MFT and store them in memory, each file record has a length of 1024 bytes, and I am interested in their $STANDARD_INFORMATION, $ATTRIBUTE_LIST, $FILE_NAME and (non-resident) $DATA attributes, because I want to resolve file record segment addresses from `D:\System Volume Information\Chkdsk\chkdskyyyymmddHHMMSS.log` to absolute file paths.

Because NTFS is very complex I won't bother describing how it works, I wrote all of the code entirely by myself, using [this](http://inform.pucp.edu.pe/%7Einf232/Ntfs/ntfs_doc_v0.5/index.html), [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NTFS) and [this](https://www.disk-editor.org/) as references.

The code is incomplete, but the core functionalities are implemented and working properly, I am trying to organize the resultant information better and make it use less memory, I have only parsed a select few attributes and flags because they are what I wanted, and other attributes will make the objects use more memory.

I have determined that if I load all 2247424 entries in the target $MFT I can expect the program to use 3GiB 376MiB 562KiB 380B memory, and I want to make it use less memory.

```
import re
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
from typing import Callable, Generator, Mapping, NamedTuple, Sequence, Set

SHORT_PATH = re.compile(r"^\w{6}~\d+\.\w{3}$")
EPOCH = datetime(1601, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0)
FILE_GOOD = ("BAAD", "FILE")
UNITS = ("B", "KiB", "MiB", "GiB", "TiB", "PiB", "EiB", "ZiB", "YiB", "RiB", "QiB")
BOOT_SECTOR = (
    (0, 3, "assembly", 0),
    (3, 11, "OEM_ID", 0),
    (11, 13, "bytes/sector", 1),
    (13, 14, "sectors/cluster", 1),
    (21, 22, "media_descriptor", 0),
    (24, 26, "sectors/track", 1),
    (26, 28, "heads", 1),
    (28, 32, "hidden_sectors", 1),
    (40, 48, "total_sectors", 1),
    (48, 56, "$MFT_cluster", 1),
    (56, 64, "$MFTMirr_cluster", 1),
    (64, 65, "FRS_length", 1),
    (72, 80, "volume_serial_number", 1),
    (84, 510, "bootstrap_code", 0),
    (510, 512, "end-of-sector", 0),
)
ATTRDEF_FLAGS = ((2, "Indexed"), (64, "Resident"), (128, "Non-Resident"))
ATTRIBUTE_TYPES = {
    16: "$STANDARD_INFORMATION",
    32: "$ATTRIBUTE_LIST",
    48: "$FILE_NAME",
    64: "$OBJECT_ID",
    80: "$SECURITY_DESCRIPTOR",
    96: "$VOLUME_NAME",
    112: "$VOLUME_INFORMATION",
    128: "$DATA",
    144: "$INDEX_ROOT",
    160: "$INDEX_ALLOCATION",
    176: "$BITMAP",
    192: "$REPARSE_POINT",
    208: "$EA_INFORMATION",
    224: "$EA",
    256: "$LOGGED_UTILITY_STREAM",
}
FILE_PERMISSIONS = (1, 2, 4, 32)
HEADER_FLAGS = (1, 2)


class Record_Header(NamedTuple):
    Written: int
    Hardlinks: int
    Record_Size: int
    Base_Record: int
    Record_ID: int
    In_Use: bool
    Directory: bool


class NonResident_Attribute(NamedTuple):
    Type: str
    Real_Size: int
    Name: str
    Data_Runs: tuple


class Resident_Attribute(NamedTuple):
    Type: str
    Name: str
    Attribute: NamedTuple


class File_Permissions(NamedTuple):
    Read_Only: bool
    Hidden: bool
    System: bool
    Archive: bool


class Standard_Information(NamedTuple):
    File_Created: datetime
    File_Modified: datetime
    Record_Changed: datetime
    Last_Access: datetime
    File_Permissions: File_Permissions


class Attribute_List_Entry(NamedTuple):
    Type: int
    Base_Record: int
    Name: str


class FileName(NamedTuple):
    Parent_Record: int
    Allocated_Size: int
    Real_Size: int
    Name: str


class File_Record(NamedTuple):
    Header: Record_Header
    Attributes: tuple


def parse_file_permissions(data: bytes) -> File_Permissions:
    flag = parse_little_endian(data)
    return File_Permissions(*(bool(flag & bit) for bit in FILE_PERMISSIONS))


def parse_NTFS_timestamp(data: bytes) -> datetime:
    return EPOCH + timedelta(seconds=int.from_bytes(data, "little") * 1e-7)


def parse_sined_little_endian(data: bytes) -> int:
    return (
        -1 * (1 + sum((b ^ 0xFF) * (1 << i * 8) for i, b in enumerate(data)))
        if data[-1] & 128
        else int.from_bytes(data, "little")
    )


def parse_little_endian(data: bytes) -> int:
    return int.from_bytes(data, "little")


def get_attribute_name(data: bytes) -> str:
    return ATTRIBUTE_TYPES[parse_little_endian(data)]


FILE_RECORD_HEADER = (
    (16, 18, parse_little_endian),
    (18, 20, parse_little_endian),
    (24, 28, parse_little_endian),
    (32, 38, parse_little_endian),
    (44, 48, parse_little_endian),
)

NONRESIDENT_HEADER = (
    (0, 4, get_attribute_name),
    (48, 56, parse_little_endian),
)


A1_STANDARD_INFORMATION = (
    (0, 8, parse_NTFS_timestamp),
    (8, 16, parse_NTFS_timestamp),
    (16, 24, parse_NTFS_timestamp),
    (24, 32, parse_NTFS_timestamp),
    (32, 36, parse_file_permissions),
)

A2_ATTRIBUTE_LIST = (
    (0, 4, get_attribute_name),
    (16, 22, parse_little_endian),
)

A3_FILENAME = (
    (0, 6, parse_little_endian),
    (40, 48, parse_little_endian),
    (48, 56, parse_little_endian),
)


def parse_standard_information(data: bytes) -> Standard_Information:
    return Standard_Information(
        *(func(data[start:end]) for start, end, func in A1_STANDARD_INFORMATION)
    )


def parse_attribute_list_gen(data: bytes) -> Generator[Attribute_List_Entry, None, None]:
    while len(data) > 26:
        offset = 26 + 2 * data[6]
        yield Attribute_List_Entry(
            *(func(data[start:end]) for start, end, func in A2_ATTRIBUTE_LIST),
            data[26:offset:2].decode(),
        )
        data = data[((offset + 7) >> 3) << 3 :]

def parse_attribute_list(data: bytes) -> tuple:
    return tuple(parse_attribute_list_gen(data))

def parse_filename(data: bytes) -> FileName:
    name = data[66 : 66 + 2 * data[64]]
    try:
        name = name.decode("utf8").replace("\x00", "")
    except UnicodeDecodeError:
        name = name.decode("utf-16-le").replace("\x00", "")
    return FileName(*(func(data[start:end]) for start, end, func in A3_FILENAME), name)


def parse_record_header(data: bytes) -> Record_Header:
    flag = parse_little_endian(data[22:24])
    return Record_Header(
        *(func(data[start:end]) for start, end, func in FILE_RECORD_HEADER),
        flag & 1,
        flag & 2,
    )


def ignore():
    pass


ATTRIBUTE_PARSERS = {
    "$STANDARD_INFORMATION": parse_standard_information,
    "$ATTRIBUTE_LIST": parse_attribute_list,
    "$FILE_NAME": parse_filename,
    "$DATA": ignore,
}


def format_size(length: int) -> str:
    string = ""
    i = 0
    while length and i < 10:
        chunk = length & 1023
        length >>= 10
        if chunk:
            string = f"{chunk}{UNITS[i]} {string}"

        i += 1

    if length:
        string = f"{length}QiB {string}"

    return string.rstrip()


def process_boot_sector(data: dict) -> None:
    data["raw_size"] = size = data["bytes/sector"] * data["total_sectors"]
    data["readable_size"] = format_size(size)
    data["bytes/cluster"] = cluster = data["bytes/sector"] * data["sectors/cluster"]
    data["$MFT_index"] = data["$MFT_cluster"] * cluster
    frs_length = data["FRS_length"]
    if frs_length < 128:
        data["FRS_length"] = frs_length * cluster
    else:
        data["FRS_length"] = 1 << (256 - frs_length)


def open_partition(drive: str) -> dict:
    partition = open(f"//?/{drive}:", "rb")
    sector = partition.read(512)
    decoded = {}
    for start, end, name, little in BOOT_SECTOR:
        data = sector[start:end]
        if little:
            data = int.from_bytes(data, "little")

        decoded[name] = data

    process_boot_sector(decoded)
    partition.seek(0)
    return {
        "handle": partition,
        "info": decoded,
    }


def decode_attrdef_name(data: bytes) -> str:
    return bytes(b for b in data if b).decode("utf8")


def decode_attrdef_flags(data: bytes) -> list:
    flag = int.from_bytes(data, "little")
    return [name for bit, name in ATTRDEF_FLAGS if flag & bit]


def parse_attrdef(data: bytes) -> dict:
    result = {}
    while data[0]:
        result[parse_little_endian(data[128:132])] = decode_attrdef_name(data[:128])
        data = data[160:]

    return result


def preprocess_file_record(data: bytes) -> bytes:
    if data[:4] != b"FILE":
        raise ValueError("File record is corrupt")

    token = data[48:50]
    if token != data[510:512] or token != data[1022:1024]:
        raise ValueError("File record is corrupt")

    update_sequence = data[50:54]
    return data[:510] + update_sequence[:2] + data[512:1022] + update_sequence[2:]


def parse_data_runs(data: bytes) -> Generator[tuple, None, None]:
    while (size := data[0]) and len(data) > 2:
        count = (size & 15) + 1
        first = (size >> 4) + count
        cluster_count = parse_little_endian(data[1:count])
        starting_cluster = parse_little_endian(data[count:first])
        data = data[first:]
        yield (starting_cluster, cluster_count)


def parse_nonresident(data: bytes, limit: int) -> list:
    name_offset = parse_little_endian(data[10:12])
    offset = parse_little_endian(data[32:34])
    name = data[name_offset:offset:2].decode() if data[9] else ""

    return NonResident_Attribute(
        *(func(data[start:end]) for start, end, func in NONRESIDENT_HEADER),
        name,
        tuple(parse_data_runs(data[offset:limit])),
    )


def parse_resident(
    data: bytes, attribute_type: str, parser: Callable
) -> Resident_Attribute:
    length = parse_little_endian(data[16:20])
    name_offset = parse_little_endian(data[10:12])
    offset = parse_little_endian(data[20:22])
    name = data[name_offset:offset:2].decode() if data[9] else ""
    return Resident_Attribute(
        attribute_type,
        name,
        parser(data[offset : offset + length]),
    )


def parse_record_attributes(data: bytes) -> Generator:
    data = data[56:]
    while data[:4] != b"\xff\xff\xff\xff":
        length = parse_little_endian(data[4:8])
        attribute_type = get_attribute_name(data[:4])
        if func := ATTRIBUTE_PARSERS.get(attribute_type):
            if data[8]:
                yield parse_nonresident(data, length)
            elif func is not ignore:
                attribute = parse_resident(data, attribute_type, func)
                if not (
                    attribute.Type == "$FILE_NAME"
                    and SHORT_PATH.match(attribute.Attribute.Name)
                ):
                    yield attribute
        data = data[length:]


def parse_file_record(data: bytes) -> File_Record:
    data = preprocess_file_record(data)
    return File_Record(parse_record_header(data), tuple(parse_record_attributes(data)))


def get_size(obj: object) -> int:
    size = obj.__sizeof__()
    if isinstance(obj, Mapping):
        size += sum(get_size(k) + get_size(v) for k, v in obj.items())
    elif isinstance(obj, Sequence | Set) and not isinstance(obj, str):
        size += sum(get_size(e) for e in obj)
    return size


if __name__ == "__main__":
    partition = open_partition("D")
    handle = partition["handle"]
    info = partition["info"]
    frs_length = info["FRS_length"]
    handle.seek(info["$MFT_index"])
    records = []

    for _ in range(65536):
        data = handle.read(1024)
        records.append(parse_file_record(data))

    print(format_size(get_size(records) // 65536))
```

Example records:

```
In [2]: records[:16]
Out[2]:
[File_Record(Header=Record_Header(Written=1, Hardlinks=1, Record_Size=408, Base_Record=0, Record_ID=0, In_Use=1, Directory=0), Attributes=(Resident_Attribute(Type='$STANDARD_INFORMATION', Name='', Attribute=Standard_Information(File_Created=datetime.datetime(2021, 3, 21, 9, 41, 47, 819000), File_Modified=datetime.datetime(2021, 3, 21, 9, 41, 47, 819000), Record_Changed=datetime.datetime(2021, 3, 21, 9, 41, 47, 819000), Last_Access=datetime.datetime(2021, 3, 21, 9, 41, 47, 819000), File_Permissions=File_Permissions(Read_Only=False, Hidden=True, System=True, Archive=False))), Resident_Attribute(Type='$FILE_NAME', Name='', Attribute=FileName(Parent_Record=5, Allocated_Size=2301362176, Real_Size=2301362176, Name='$MFT')), NonResident_Attribute(Type='$DATA', Real_Size=2301362176, Name='', Data_Runs=((2, 561856),)))),
 File_Record(Header=Record_Header(Written=1, Hardlinks=1, Record_Size=344, Base_Record=0, Record_ID=1, In_Use=1, Directory=0), Attributes=(Resident_Attribute(Type='$STANDARD_INFORMATION', Name='', Attribute=Standard_Information(File_Created=datetime.datetime(2021, 3, 21, 9, 41, 47, 819000), File_Modified=datetime.datetime(2021, 3, 21, 9, 41, 47, 819000), Record_Changed=datetime.datetime(2021, 3, 21, 9, 41, 47, 819000), Last_Access=datetime.datetime(2021, 3, 21, 9, 41, 47, 819000), File_Permissions=File_Permissions(Read_Only=False, Hidden=True, System=True, Archive=False))), Resident_Attribute(Type='$FILE_NAME', Name='', Attribute=FileName(Parent_Record=5, Allocated_Size=4096, Real_Size=4096, Name='$MFTMirr')), NonResident_Attribute(Type='$DATA', Real_Size=4096, Name='', Data_Runs=((171046397, 1),)))),
 File_Record(Header=Record_Header(Written=2, Hardlinks=1, Record_Size=344, Base_Record=0, Record_ID=2, In_Use=1, Directory=0), Attributes=(Resident_Attribute(Type='$STANDARD_INFORMATION', Name='', Attribute=Standard_Information(File_Created=datetime.datetime(2021, 3, 21, 9, 41, 47, 819000), File_Modified=datetime.datetime(2021, 3, 21, 9, 41, 47, 819000), Record_Changed=datetime.datetime(2021, 3, 21, 9, 41, 47, 819000), Last_Access=datetime.datetime(2021, 3, 21, 9, 41, 47, 819000), File_Permissions=File_Permissions(Read_Only=False, Hidden=True, System=True, Archive=False))), Resident_Attribute(Type='$FILE_NAME', Name='', Attribute=FileName(Parent_Record=5, Allocated_Size=67108864, Real_Size=67108864, Name='$LogFile')), NonResident_Attribute(Type='$DATA', Real_Size=67108864, Name='', Data_Runs=((573699706, 16384),)))),
 File_Record(Header=Record_Header(Written=3, Hardlinks=1, Record_Size=416, Base_Record=0, Record_ID=3, In_Use=1, Directory=0), Attributes=(Resident_Attribute(Type='$STANDARD_INFORMATION', Name='', Attribute=Standard_Information(File_Created=datetime.datetime(2021, 3, 21, 9, 41, 47, 819000), File_Modified=datetime.datetime(2021, 3, 21, 9, 41, 47, 819000), Record_Changed=datetime.datetime(2021, 3, 21, 9, 41, 47, 819000), Last_Access=datetime.datetime(2021, 3, 21, 9, 41, 47, 819000), File_Permissions=File_Permissions(Read_Only=False, Hidden=True, System=True, Archive=False))), Resident_Attribute(Type='$FILE_NAME', Name='', Attribute=FileName(Parent_Record=5, Allocated_Size=0, Real_Size=0, Name='$Volume')))),
 File_Record(Header=Record_Header(Written=4, Hardlinks=1, Record_Size=344, Base_Record=0, Record_ID=4, In_Use=1, Directory=0), Attributes=(Resident_Attribute(Type='$STANDARD_INFORMATION', Name='', Attribute=Standard_Information(File_Created=datetime.datetime(2021, 3, 21, 9, 41, 47, 819000), File_Modified=datetime.datetime(2021, 3, 21, 9, 41, 47, 819000), Record_Changed=datetime.datetime(2021, 3, 21, 9, 41, 47, 819000), Last_Access=datetime.datetime(2021, 3, 21, 9, 41, 47, 819000), File_Permissions=File_Permissions(Read_Only=False, Hidden=True, System=True, Archive=False))), Resident_Attribute(Type='$FILE_NAME', Name='', Attribute=FileName(Parent_Record=5, Allocated_Size=4096, Real_Size=2560, Name='$AttrDef')), NonResident_Attribute(Type='$DATA', Real_Size=2560, Name='', Data_Runs=((165002433, 1),)))),
 File_Record(Header=Record_Header(Written=5, Hardlinks=1, Record_Size=768, Base_Record=0, Record_ID=5, In_Use=1, Directory=2), Attributes=(Resident_Attribute(Type='$STANDARD_INFORMATION', Name='', Attribute=Standard_Information(File_Created=datetime.datetime(2021, 3, 21, 9, 41, 47, 819000), File_Modified=datetime.datetime(2024, 1, 29, 14, 58, 44, 660774), Record_Changed=datetime.datetime(2024, 1, 29, 14, 58, 44, 660774), Last_Access=datetime.datetime(2024, 1, 29, 14, 58, 45, 661135), File_Permissions=File_Permissions(Read_Only=False, Hidden=True, System=True, Archive=False))), Resident_Attribute(Type='$FILE_NAME', Name='', Attribute=FileName(Parent_Record=5, Allocated_Size=0, Real_Size=0, Name='.')))),
 File_Record(Header=Record_Header(Written=6, Hardlinks=1, Record_Size=344, Base_Record=0, Record_ID=6, In_Use=1, Directory=0), Attributes=(Resident_Attribute(Type='$STANDARD_INFORMATION', Name='', Attribute=Standard_Information(File_Created=datetime.datetime(2021, 3, 21, 9, 41, 47, 819000), File_Modified=datetime.datetime(2021, 3, 21, 9, 41, 47, 819000), Record_Changed=datetime.datetime(2021, 3, 21, 9, 41, 47, 819000), Last_Access=datetime.datetime(2021, 3, 21, 9, 41, 47, 819000), File_Permissions=File_Permissions(Read_Only=False, Hidden=True, System=True, Archive=False))), Resident_Attribute(Type='$FILE_NAME', Name='', Attribute=FileName(Parent_Record=5, Allocated_Size=122044416, Real_Size=122044128, Name='$Bitmap')), NonResident_Attribute(Type='$DATA', Real_Size=122044128, Name='', Data_Runs=((171046398, 24577), (4124482825, 5219))))),
 File_Record(Header=Record_Header(Written=7, Hardlinks=1, Record_Size=440, Base_Record=0, Record_ID=7, In_Use=1, Directory=0), Attributes=(Resident_Attribute(Type='$STANDARD_INFORMATION', Name='', Attribute=Standard_Information(File_Created=datetime.datetime(2021, 3, 21, 9, 41, 47, 819000), File_Modified=datetime.datetime(2021, 3, 21, 9, 41, 47, 819000), Record_Changed=datetime.datetime(2021, 3, 21, 9, 41, 47, 819000), Last_Access=datetime.datetime(2021, 3, 21, 9, 41, 47, 819000), File_Permissions=File_Permissions(Read_Only=False, Hidden=True, System=True, Archive=False))), Resident_Attribute(Type='$FILE_NAME', Name='', Attribute=FileName(Parent_Record=5, Allocated_Size=8192, Real_Size=8192, Name='$Boot')), NonResident_Attribute(Type='$DATA', Real_Size=8192, Name='', Data_Runs=((0, 2),)))),
 File_Record(Header=Record_Header(Written=8, Hardlinks=1, Record_Size=376, Base_Record=0, Record_ID=8, In_Use=1, Directory=0), Attributes=(Resident_Attribute(Type='$STANDARD_INFORMATION', Name='', Attribute=Standard_Information(File_Created=datetime.datetime(2021, 3, 21, 9, 41, 47, 819000), File_Modified=datetime.datetime(2021, 3, 21, 9, 41, 47, 819000), Record_Changed=datetime.datetime(2021, 3, 21, 9, 41, 47, 819000), Last_Access=datetime.datetime(2021, 3, 21, 9, 41, 47, 819000), File_Permissions=File_Permissions(Read_Only=False, Hidden=True, System=True, Archive=False))), Resident_Attribute(Type='$FILE_NAME', Name='', Attribute=FileName(Parent_Record=5, Allocated_Size=0, Real_Size=0, Name='$BadClus')), NonResident_Attribute(Type='$DATA', Real_Size=3999141965824, Name='$Bad', Data_Runs=((0, 976353019),)))),
 File_Record(Header=Record_Header(Written=9, Hardlinks=1, Record_Size=968, Base_Record=0, Record_ID=9, In_Use=1, Directory=0), Attributes=(Resident_Attribute(Type='$STANDARD_INFORMATION', Name='', Attribute=Standard_Information(File_Created=datetime.datetime(2021, 3, 21, 9, 41, 47, 819000), File_Modified=datetime.datetime(2021, 3, 21, 9, 41, 47, 819000), Record_Changed=datetime.datetime(2021, 3, 21, 9, 41, 47, 819000), Last_Access=datetime.datetime(2021, 3, 21, 9, 41, 47, 819000), File_Permissions=File_Permissions(Read_Only=False, Hidden=True, System=True, Archive=False))), Resident_Attribute(Type='$FILE_NAME', Name='', Attribute=FileName(Parent_Record=5, Allocated_Size=0, Real_Size=0, Name='$Secure')), NonResident_Attribute(Type='$DATA', Real_Size=319444, Name='$SDS', Data_Runs=((684234, 78),)))),
 File_Record(Header=Record_Header(Written=10, Hardlinks=1, Record_Size=408, Base_Record=0, Record_ID=10, In_Use=1, Directory=0), Attributes=(Resident_Attribute(Type='$STANDARD_INFORMATION', Name='', Attribute=Standard_Information(File_Created=datetime.datetime(2021, 3, 21, 9, 41, 47, 819000), File_Modified=datetime.datetime(2021, 3, 21, 9, 41, 47, 819000), Record_Changed=datetime.datetime(2021, 3, 21, 9, 41, 47, 819000), Last_Access=datetime.datetime(2021, 3, 21, 9, 41, 47, 819000), File_Permissions=File_Permissions(Read_Only=False, Hidden=True, System=True, Archive=False))), Resident_Attribute(Type='$FILE_NAME', Name='', Attribute=FileName(Parent_Record=5, Allocated_Size=131072, Real_Size=131072, Name='$UpCase')), NonResident_Attribute(Type='$DATA', Real_Size=131072, Name='', Data_Runs=((158628201, 32),)))),
 File_Record(Header=Record_Header(Written=11, Hardlinks=1, Record_Size=952, Base_Record=0, Record_ID=11, In_Use=1, Directory=2), Attributes=(Resident_Attribute(Type='$STANDARD_INFORMATION', Name='', Attribute=Standard_Information(File_Created=datetime.datetime(2021, 3, 21, 9, 41, 47, 819000), File_Modified=datetime.datetime(2021, 3, 21, 9, 41, 47, 819000), Record_Changed=datetime.datetime(2021, 3, 21, 9, 41, 47, 819000), Last_Access=datetime.datetime(2023, 3, 13, 17, 37, 23, 724527), File_Permissions=File_Permissions(Read_Only=False, Hidden=True, System=True, Archive=False))), Resident_Attribute(Type='$FILE_NAME', Name='', Attribute=FileName(Parent_Record=5, Allocated_Size=0, Real_Size=0, Name='$Extend')))),
 File_Record(Header=Record_Header(Written=12, Hardlinks=0, Record_Size=288, Base_Record=0, Record_ID=12, In_Use=1, Directory=0), Attributes=(Resident_Attribute(Type='$STANDARD_INFORMATION', Name='', Attribute=Standard_Information(File_Created=datetime.datetime(2021, 3, 21, 9, 41, 47, 819000), File_Modified=datetime.datetime(2021, 3, 21, 9, 41, 47, 819000), Record_Changed=datetime.datetime(2021, 3, 21, 9, 41, 47, 819000), Last_Access=datetime.datetime(2021, 3, 21, 9, 41, 47, 819000), File_Permissions=File_Permissions(Read_Only=False, Hidden=True, System=True, Archive=False))),)),
 File_Record(Header=Record_Header(Written=13, Hardlinks=0, Record_Size=288, Base_Record=0, Record_ID=13, In_Use=1, Directory=0), Attributes=(Resident_Attribute(Type='$STANDARD_INFORMATION', Name='', Attribute=Standard_Information(File_Created=datetime.datetime(2021, 3, 21, 9, 41, 47, 819000), File_Modified=datetime.datetime(2021, 3, 21, 9, 41, 47, 819000), Record_Changed=datetime.datetime(2021, 3, 21, 9, 41, 47, 819000), Last_Access=datetime.datetime(2021, 3, 21, 9, 41, 47, 819000), File_Permissions=File_Permissions(Read_Only=False, Hidden=True, System=True, Archive=False))),)),
 File_Record(Header=Record_Header(Written=14, Hardlinks=0, Record_Size=288, Base_Record=0, Record_ID=14, In_Use=1, Directory=0), Attributes=(Resident_Attribute(Type='$STANDARD_INFORMATION', Name='', Attribute=Standard_Information(File_Created=datetime.datetime(2021, 3, 21, 9, 41, 47, 819000), File_Modified=datetime.datetime(2021, 3, 21, 9, 41, 47, 819000), Record_Changed=datetime.datetime(2021, 3, 21, 9, 41, 47, 819000), Last_Access=datetime.datetime(2021, 3, 21, 9, 41, 47, 819000), File_Permissions=File_Permissions(Read_Only=False, Hidden=True, System=True, Archive=False))),)),
 File_Record(Header=Record_Header(Written=15, Hardlinks=0, Record_Size=288, Base_Record=0, Record_ID=15, In_Use=1, Directory=0), Attributes=(Resident_Attribute(Type='$STANDARD_INFORMATION', Name='', Attribute=Standard_Information(File_Created=datetime.datetime(2021, 3, 21, 9, 41, 47, 819000), File_Modified=datetime.datetime(2021, 3, 21, 9, 41, 47, 819000), Record_Changed=datetime.datetime(2021, 3, 21, 9, 41, 47, 819000), Last_Access=datetime.datetime(2021, 3, 21, 9, 41, 47, 819000), File_Permissions=File_Permissions(Read_Only=False, Hidden=True, System=True, Archive=False))),))]
```

How can I improve this program?

---

### Edit

Minor oversight, in the original code `$ATTRIBUTE_LIST` entries won't be parsed but a generator object will be created, the data isn't stored in memory and this is unintended. I have fixed it.

Comment: I don't see a way around using at least as much memory as the data structures themselves. 2 things that stand out to me are: packed structs in Cython, and using a generator approach if you can seek records in the MFT

Comment: Have you tried [any of the off-the-shelf options](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20717829/trying-to-get-mft-table-from-python-3) - pyMFTGrabber, analyzeMFT, etc.?

Comment: @Reinderien I have looked into them before I wrote this program and they aren't looking great, all those I have investigated were written for Python 2 and their code quality is very poor, at least much poorer than mine. And that is why I wrote this program. And I need the raw data in memory, I am not looking for human readable serialization because I need the data for further processing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In `UNITS` you should split the IEC prefix (Mi, Gi, etc.) away from the unit `B`.

`BOOT_SECTOR` is not structured enough - it's entirely unclear what those four fields are, and this could be fixed by constructing from each of those sequences a named tuple. Further, though, those seem like field offsets with names, so you should throw the whole thing away and use a proper `ctypes` structure definition. This pattern occurs multiple times through your code. The theme is - reduce the amount of magic-number offsets in your code, and move away from *imperative decoding* and toward *declarative decoding*.

`timedelta(seconds=int.from_bytes(data, "little") * 1e-7)` is incorrectly using `seconds` and a large multiplier, when it should use `microseconds` and a smaller multiplier.

Never write `-1 *`; use a unary negation `-` instead.

`parse_sined` should be spelled `parse_signed`. More importantly, that method is doing a lot of manual bit-munging that should be deleted and replaced with proper `ctypes` and `struct` unpacking calls.

In `format_size`, re-formatting of the style `string = f'{string}'` is not efficient. Ideally this would be split into two functions - one a generator yielding string fragments, and the outer function performing a `join`.

Why would you `rstrip` on a string you've constructed yourself?

Use of `data: dict` is poorly typed for a few reasons. First, don't use `dict` without specifying its inner types. More importantly, don't use `dict` at all; pass around immutable structures. "Processing" a data dictionary by mutating it after only half of it has been constructed is an anti-pattern; typical solutions are to split it into two objects, or perform construction of all of the values at once in a `@classmethod`.

There's more, but that (especially use of `ctypes`) will go a long way.