# Resolve an entire NTFS Master File Table's worth of File Records to Absolute Paths

Tags: python, performance, file-system

This is related to my [previous question](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/289225/python-master-file-table-parser/).

This is it, the full working code that resolves all file record segments in a Master File Table to absolute file paths. It is completely working and seems to working perfectly as I have manually checked dozens of the results against [Active Disk Editor](https://www.disk-editor.org/) and have determined them to be correct. But I haven't checked that many results so there might be bugs, but that possibility is quite small.

This is the craziest thing I have done so far, in the beginning I completely had no idea what I was doing, and I had to learn and improvise. I wrote all of the code entirely by myself, using [this documentation](http://inform.pucp.edu.pe/%7Einf232/Ntfs/ntfs_doc_v0.5/) and Active Disk Editor as references.

Because NTFS is quite complex, I won't describe the technical "how" of it. Refer to the links if you don't understand.

My motivation is simple, there was a power outage in my home and my computer's filesystems were corrupted as a result. I had run `chkdsk /f X:` and there were thousands of messages like this:

```
Attribute record of type 0x80 and instance tag 0x4 is cross linked
starting at 0x93840c0 for possibly 0x95 clusters.
Some clusters occupied by attribute of type 0x80 and instance tag 0x4
in file 0x46c5 is already in use.
Deleting corrupt attribute record (0x80, "")
from file record segment 0x46C5.
```

The log from "D:\System Volume Information\Chkdsk" said 107855 data files were processed.
I guess they are corrupt and so I want to identify the files and delete them.

I wanted to resolve absolute file path using file record segment, and days of Google searching proved futile, so I asked [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/1826824/how-to-identify-file-by-file-record-segment/1826842#1826842) on Super User. And in the past week I went down the rabbit hole of NTFS and wrote this.

I will try to describe what the program does. First, trying to `open("//?/D:/$MFT", "rb")` raises `PermissionDenied` exception even with Administrative privileges. So I circumvented it by `open("//?/D:", "rb")` with admin rights to create a handle to the boot sector.

Then I read the boot sector to get the file record segment length (1024 bytes), bytes per cluster and $MFT starting cluster, then calculate the offset in bytes to the $MFT file record 0, and calculate the maximum count of the file record segments.

I then iterate through the whole table using `handle.seek` and `handle.read(1024)` to load all file records and get their `$STANDARD_INFORMATION`, `$ATTRIBUTE_LIST`, `$FILE_NAME` and `$DATA` (non-resident attributes). I only load some of the information to save memory size.

The listed size of $MFT is 2,301,362,176 bytes or 2GiB 146MiB 768KiB, and that corresponds to 2,247,424 entries, but there are only 2,247,202 filled entries, 711,382 are marked as unused. I only store entries marked as in-use, and despite my best efforts loading and storing all 1,535,820 entries in memory takes about 4GiB RAM.

In the 1,535,820 entries that I am interested in, many don't have `$FILE_NAME` attributes (hard_link count is 0), and they have non-zero base record in the header which means the filename is stored else where, some other records have only DOS names, and some records don't have `$FILE_NAME` attributes but have an `$ATTRIBUTE_LIST` attribute...

And all `$FILE_NAME` attributes don't store absolute file paths and they only have a reference to the parent record, requiring recursive resolving...

And so I wrote a gigantic class with 168 lines of code to sort through all that to resolve all file record segments to absolute file paths, and I have done it.

---

### ***Code***

```py
from __future__ import annotations
import ctypes
import re
import struct
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
from typing import (
    Any,
    Generator,
    Iterable,
    List,
    Sequence,
    Tuple,
)


SHORT_PATH = re.compile(r"^.{6}~\d+(\.\w{3})?$")
UINT48 = (1 << 48) - 1
EPOCH = datetime(1601, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0)
UNITS = ("B", "KiB", "MiB", "GiB", "TiB", "PiB", "EiB", "ZiB", "YiB", "RiB", "QiB")
QUARTERGB = 268435456


def group_consecutive(numbers: Iterable[int]) -> List[Tuple[int, int]]:
    result = []
    start = end = numbers[0]
    for n in numbers[1:]:
        if n - 1 == end:
            end = n
        else:
            result.append((start, end - start + 1))
            start = end = n

    result.append((start, end - start + 1))
    return result


def to_timestamp(dt: datetime) -> str:
    return dt.strftime("%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ")


def format_size_gen(length: int) -> Generator[str, None, None]:
    i = 0
    while length and i < 10:
        chunk = length & 1023
        length >>= 10
        if chunk:
            yield f"{chunk}{UNITS[i]}"

        i += 1

    if length:
        yield f"{length}QiB"


def format_size(length: int) -> str:
    return " ".join(reversed(list(format_size_gen(length))))


def parse_NTFS_timestamp(data: int) -> datetime:
    return EPOCH + timedelta(microseconds=data * 0.1)


def parse_little_endian(data: bytes) -> int:
    return int.from_bytes(data, "little")


def __repr__(self) -> str:
    return (
        f"{self.__class__.__name__}("
        + ", ".join(f"{field}={getattr(self, field)!r}" for field in self.__names__)
        + ")"
    )


def to_dict(self) -> dict:
    return {key: getattr(self, key) for key in self.__names__}


def get_size(self) -> int:
    return ctypes.sizeof(self)


def patcher(cls):
    cls.__repr__ = __repr__
    cls.to_dict = to_dict
    cls.get_size = get_size
    return cls


@patcher
class Boot_Sector(ctypes.Structure):
    __slots__ = ()
    __names__ = (
        "Bytes_per_Sector",
        "Sectors_per_Cluster",
        "Hidden_Sectors",
        "Total_Sectors",
        "MFT_Cluster",
        "MFTMirr_Cluster",
        "FRS_Length",
        "Volume_Serial_Number",
        "Bytes_per_Cluster",
        "MFT_Index",
        "Raw_Size",
        "Readable_Size",
    )
    _fields_ = (
        ("Bytes_per_Sector", ctypes.c_uint16),
        ("Sectors_per_Cluster", ctypes.c_uint8),
        ("Hidden_Sectors", ctypes.c_uint32),
        ("Total_Sectors", ctypes.c_uint64),
        ("MFT_Cluster", ctypes.c_uint64),
        ("MFTMirr_Cluster", ctypes.c_uint64),
        ("FRS_Length", ctypes.c_uint16),
        ("Volume_Serial_Number", ctypes.c_uint64),
        ("Bytes_per_Cluster", ctypes.c_uint32),
        ("MFT_Index", ctypes.c_uint64),
        ("Raw_Size", ctypes.c_uint64),
    )

    @property
    def Readable_Size(self) -> str:
        return format_size(self.Raw_Size)

    @classmethod
    def parse(cls, data: bytes) -> Boot_Sector:
        parsed = dict(
            zip(
                Boot_Sector.__names__[:8],
                struct.unpack("<11xHB14xL8x3Qb7xQ", data[:80]),
            )
        )
        parsed["Bytes_per_Cluster"] = cluster = (
            sector := parsed["Bytes_per_Sector"]
        ) * parsed["Sectors_per_Cluster"]
        parsed["MFT_Index"] = parsed["MFT_Cluster"] * cluster
        parsed["Raw_Size"] = sector * parsed["Total_Sectors"]
        if (frs_length := parsed["FRS_Length"]) > 0:
            parsed["FRS_Length"] *= cluster
        else:
            parsed["FRS_Length"] = 1 << (-frs_length)
        return cls(*parsed.values())


class DotTuple(Sequence):
    def __getitem__(self, key: int | slice) -> Any:
        if isinstance(key, int):
            return getattr(self, self.__names__[key])
        elif isinstance(key, slice):
            return [self[i] for i in range(key.start, key.stop, key.step)]

    def __len__(self) -> int:
        return len(self.__names__)

    def __iter__(self) -> Generator:
        yield from (self[k] for k in self.__names__)


@patcher
class Record_Header(ctypes.Structure):
    __slots__ = ()
    __names__ = (
        "Written",
        "HardLinks",
        "In_Use",
        "Directory",
        "Base_Record",
        "Record_ID",
    )
    _fields_ = (
        ("Written", ctypes.c_uint16),
        ("HardLinks", ctypes.c_uint16),
        ("In_Use", ctypes.c_bool),
        ("Directory", ctypes.c_bool),
        ("Base_Record", ctypes.c_uint32),
        ("Record_ID", ctypes.c_uint32),
    )

    @classmethod
    def parse(cls, data: bytes) -> Record_Header:
        chunks = struct.unpack("<16xHH2xH8xQ4xL", data[:48])
        flag = chunks[2]
        return cls(
            *chunks[:2], bool(flag & 1), bool(flag & 2), chunks[3] & UINT48, chunks[4]
        )


@patcher
class Data_Run(ctypes.Structure):
    __slots__ = ()
    __names__ = ("First_Cluster", "Cluster_Count")
    _fields_ = (("First_Cluster", ctypes.c_uint32), ("Cluster_Count", ctypes.c_uint32))


def parse_attribute_name(data: bytes, name_length: int, name_offset: int) -> str:
    return (
        data[name_offset : name_offset + 2 * name_length : 2].decode("utf8")
        if name_length
        else ""
    )


class NonResident_Attribute(ctypes.Structure):
    __repr__ = __repr__
    __slots__ = ()
    __names__ = (
        "Type",
        "Attribute_ID",
        "Allocated_Size",
        "Real_Size",
        "Attribute_Name",
        "Count",
        "Data_Runs",
    )
    _fields_ = (
        ("Type", ctypes.c_uint8),
        ("Attribute_ID", ctypes.c_uint16),
        ("Allocated_Size", ctypes.c_uint64),
        ("Real_Size", ctypes.c_uint64),
        ("Attribute_Name", ctypes.c_wchar_p),
        ("Count", ctypes.c_uint8),
        ("Data_Runs", ctypes.POINTER(Data_Run)),
    )

    @staticmethod
    def parse_data_runs(data: bytes) -> Generator[Data_Run, None, None]:
        while (size := data[0]) and len(data) > 2:
            count = (size & 15) + 1
            first = (size >> 4) + count
            cluster_count = parse_little_endian(data[1:count])
            starting_cluster = parse_little_endian(data[count:first])
            data = data[first:]
            yield Data_Run(starting_cluster, cluster_count)

    @staticmethod
    def get_data_runs(data: bytes) -> Tuple[int, ctypes.POINTER(Data_Run)]:
        data_runs = list(NonResident_Attribute.parse_data_runs(data))
        l = len(data_runs)
        return l, ctypes.cast((Data_Run * l)(*data_runs), ctypes.POINTER(Data_Run))

    @classmethod
    def parse(cls, data: bytes, data_type: int) -> NonResident_Attribute:
        chunks = struct.unpack("<9xBH2xH16xH6xQQ", data[:56])
        name = parse_attribute_name(data, chunks[0], chunks[1])
        l, data_runs = NonResident_Attribute.get_data_runs(data[chunks[3] :])
        return cls(data_type, chunks[2], *chunks[4:], name, l, data_runs)

    def to_dict(self) -> dict:
        return {key: getattr(self, key) for key in self.__names__[:6]} | {
            "Data_Runs": [self.Data_Runs[i].to_dict() for i in range(self.Count)]
        }

    def get_size(self) -> int:
        return ctypes.sizeof(self) + sum(
            ctypes.sizeof(self.Data_Runs[i]) for i in range(self.Count)
        )


def preprocess_resident(data: bytes) -> Tuple[bytes, int, str]:
    name_length, name_offset, attribute_id, data_length, data_offset = struct.unpack(
        "<9xBH2xHLH", data[:22]
    )
    return (
        data[data_offset : data_offset + data_length],
        attribute_id,
        parse_attribute_name(data, name_length, name_offset),
    )


class Standard_Information(ctypes.Structure):
    __repr__ = __repr__
    get_size = get_size
    __slots__ = ()
    __names__ = (
        "Attribute_ID",
        "File_Created",
        "File_Modified",
        "Record_Changed",
        "Last_Access",
        "Read_Only",
        "Hidden",
        "System",
        "Attribute_Name",
    )
    _fields_ = (
        ("Attribute_ID", ctypes.c_uint16),
        ("_file_created", ctypes.c_uint64),
        ("_file_modified", ctypes.c_uint64),
        ("_record_changed", ctypes.c_uint64),
        ("_last_access", ctypes.c_uint64),
        ("Read_Only", ctypes.c_bool),
        ("Hidden", ctypes.c_bool),
        ("System", ctypes.c_bool),
        ("Attribute_Name", ctypes.c_wchar_p),
    )

    @property
    def File_Created(self) -> datetime:
        return parse_NTFS_timestamp(self._file_created)

    @property
    def File_Modified(self) -> datetime:
        return parse_NTFS_timestamp(self._file_modified)

    @property
    def Record_Changed(self) -> datetime:
        return parse_NTFS_timestamp(self._record_changed)

    @property
    def Last_Access(self) -> datetime:
        return parse_NTFS_timestamp(self._last_access)

    @classmethod
    def parse(cls, data: bytes) -> Standard_Information:
        data, attribute_id, name = preprocess_resident(data)
        chunks = struct.unpack("<4QL", data[:36])
        flag = chunks[4]
        return cls(
            attribute_id, *chunks[:4], *(bool(flag & i) for i in (1, 2, 4)), name
        )

    def to_dict(self) -> dict:
        return (
            {"Attribute_ID": self.Attribute_ID}
            | {key: to_timestamp(getattr(self, key)) for key in self.__names__[1:5]}
            | {key: getattr(self, key) for key in self.__names__[5:]}
        )


@patcher
class Attribute_List_Entry(ctypes.Structure):
    __slots__ = ()
    __names__ = ("Type", "Base_Record", "Attribute_ID", "Attribute_Name")
    _fields_ = (
        ("Type", ctypes.c_uint8),
        ("Base_Record", ctypes.c_uint32),
        ("Attribute_ID", ctypes.c_uint16),
        ("Attribute_Name", ctypes.c_wchar_p),
    )

    @classmethod
    def parse(cls, data: bytes) -> Attribute_List_Entry:
        (
            attribute_type,
            name_length,
            name_offset,
            base_record,
            attribute_id,
        ) = struct.unpack("<L2xBB8xQH", data[:26])
        return cls(
            attribute_type,
            base_record & UINT48,
            attribute_id,
            parse_attribute_name(data, name_length, name_offset),
        )


class Attribute_List(ctypes.Structure):
    __repr__ = __repr__
    __slots__ = ()
    __names__ = ("Attribute_ID", "Attribute_Name", "Count", "List")
    _fields_ = (
        ("Attribute_ID", ctypes.c_uint16),
        ("Attribute_Name", ctypes.c_wchar_p),
        ("Count", ctypes.c_uint8),
        ("List", ctypes.POINTER(Attribute_List_Entry)),
    )

    @staticmethod
    def parse_attribute_list(
        data: bytes,
    ) -> Generator[Attribute_List_Entry, None, None]:
        while len(data) > 26:
            offset = 26 + 2 * data[6]
            yield Attribute_List_Entry.parse(data)
            data = data[((offset + 7) >> 3) << 3 :]

    @classmethod
    def parse(cls, data: bytes) -> Attribute_List:
        data, attribute_id, name = preprocess_resident(data)
        attributes = list(Attribute_List.parse_attribute_list(data))
        return cls(
            attribute_id,
            name,
            (l := len(attributes)),
            ctypes.cast(
                (Attribute_List_Entry * l)(*attributes),
                ctypes.POINTER(Attribute_List_Entry),
            ),
        )

    def to_dict(self) -> dict:
        return {key: getattr(self, key) for key in self.__names__[:3]} | {
            "List": [self.List[i].to_dict() for i in range(self.Count)]
        }

    def get_size(self) -> int:
        return ctypes.sizeof(self) + sum(
            ctypes.sizeof(self.List[i]) for i in range(self.Count)
        )


@patcher
class FileName(ctypes.Structure):
    NAMESPACES = ("POSIX", "Win32", "DOS", "Win32+DOS")
    __slots__ = ()
    __names__ = (
        "Attribute_ID",
        "Parent_Record",
        "Allocated_Size",
        "Real_Size",
        "Name_Space",
        "File_Name",
        "Attribute_Name",
    )
    _fields_ = (
        ("Attribute_ID", ctypes.c_uint16),
        ("Parent_Record", ctypes.c_uint32),
        ("Allocated_Size", ctypes.c_uint64),
        ("Real_Size", ctypes.c_uint64),
        ("_name_space", ctypes.c_uint8),
        ("File_Name", ctypes.c_wchar_p),
        ("Attribute_Name", ctypes.c_wchar_p),
    )

    @property
    def Name_Space(self) -> str:
        return FileName.NAMESPACES[self._name_space]

    @staticmethod
    def parse_file_name(data: bytes) -> str:
        name_data = data[66 : 66 + 2 * data[64]]
        try:
            return name_data.decode("utf8").replace("\x00", "")
        except UnicodeDecodeError:
            return name_data.decode("utf-16-le").replace("\x00", "")

    @classmethod
    def parse(cls, data: bytes) -> FileName:
        data, attribute_id, attribute_name = preprocess_resident(data)
        parent_record, allocated_size, real_size, namespace = struct.unpack(
            "<Q32xQQ9xB", data[:66]
        )
        return cls(
            attribute_id,
            parent_record & UINT48,
            allocated_size,
            real_size,
            namespace,
            FileName.parse_file_name(data),
            attribute_name,
        )


class File_Record(DotTuple):
    __repr__ = __repr__
    __slots__ = ("Header", "Attributes")
    __names__ = __slots__
    parsers = {
        16: Standard_Information,
        32: Attribute_List,
        48: FileName,
    }

    def __init__(self, header: Record_Header, attributes: tuple) -> None:
        self.Header = header
        self.Attributes = attributes

    @staticmethod
    def preprocess_file_record(data: bytes) -> bytes:
        if data[:4] != b"FILE":
            raise ValueError("File record is corrupt")

        token = data[48:50]
        if token != data[510:512] or token != data[1022:1024]:
            raise ValueError("File record is corrupt")

        update_sequence = data[50:54]
        return data[:510] + update_sequence[:2] + data[512:1022] + update_sequence[2:]

    @staticmethod
    def parse_record_attributes(data: bytes) -> Generator:
        data = data[56:]
        while data[:4] != b"\xff\xff\xff\xff":
            length = parse_little_endian(data[4:8])
            attribute_type = parse_little_endian(data[:4])
            if data[8]:
                if attribute_type in (32, 128):
                    yield NonResident_Attribute.parse(data[:length], attribute_type)
            elif cls := File_Record.parsers.get(attribute_type):
                yield cls.parse(data)

            data = data[length:]

    @classmethod
    def parse(cls, data: bytes) -> File_Record:
        data = File_Record.preprocess_file_record(data)
        return cls(
            Record_Header.parse(data),
            tuple(File_Record.parse_record_attributes(data)),
        )

    def get_size(self) -> int:
        return (
            self.__sizeof__()
            + self.Header.get_size()
            + self.Attributes.__sizeof__()
            + sum(attr.get_size() for attr in self.Attributes)
        )

    def to_dict(self) -> dict:
        return {
            "Header": self.Header.to_dict(),
            "Attributes": [attr.to_dict() for attr in self.Attributes],
        }


class Partition:
    @staticmethod
    def decode_attrdef_name(data: bytes) -> str:
        return bytes(b for b in data if b).decode("utf8")

    def parse_attrdef(self) -> None:
        for attr in self.load_file_record(4).Attributes:
            if isinstance(attr, NonResident_Attribute) and attr.Type == 128:
                run = attr.Data_Runs[0]
                data = self.load_clusters(run.First_Cluster, run.Cluster_Count)
                break

        while data[0]:
            self.ATTRDEF[
                parse_little_endian(data[128:132])
            ] = Partition.decode_attrdef_name(data[:128])
            data = data[160:]

    def get_mft_count(self) -> None:
        for attr in self.load_file_record(0).Attributes:
            if isinstance(attr, FileName):
                self.MFT_Count = attr.Allocated_Size // self.FRS_Length
                break

    def __init__(self, drive: str) -> None:
        self.Letter = drive
        self.Handle = open(f"//?/{drive}:", "rb")
        self.Boot_Sector = Boot_Sector.parse(self.Handle.read(512))
        self.MFT_Index = self.Boot_Sector.MFT_Index
        self.FRS_Length = self.Boot_Sector.FRS_Length
        self.Cluster_Length = self.Boot_Sector.Bytes_per_Cluster
        self.ATTRDEF = {}
        self.Names = {5: "."}
        self.Unused = set()
        self.Nameless = {}
        self.Processsed = set()
        self.get_mft_count()
        self.parse_attrdef()

    def load_file_record(self, file: int) -> File_Record:
        self.jumped = True
        self.Handle.seek(self.MFT_Index + self.FRS_Length * file)
        return File_Record.parse(self.Handle.read(self.FRS_Length))

    def load_clusters(self, start: int, count: int) -> bytes:
        self.Handle.seek(start * self.Cluster_Length)
        return self.Handle.read(count * self.Cluster_Length)

    def resolve_MFT_names(self) -> None:
        self.Handle.seek(self.MFT_Index)
        self.jumped = False
        for i in range(self.MFT_Count):
            if i in self.Processsed:
                self.jumped = True
                continue
            if self.jumped:
                self.Handle.seek(self.MFT_Index + self.FRS_Length * i)
                self.jumped = False

            data = self.Handle.read(self.FRS_Length)
            if not any(data[:4]):
                break

            self.resolve_MFT_names_worker(data, i)

    def resolve_MFT_names_worker(self, data: bytes, i: int) -> None:
        record = File_Record.parse(data)
        file = record.Header.Record_ID
        assert file == i
        self.Processsed.add(i)
        if not record.Header.In_Use:
            self.Unused.add(i)
        else:
            self.resolve_MFT_name(file, record)

    def find_nameless_files(self, file: int, attributes: Attribute_List) -> None:
        if attributes:
            for i in range(attributes.Count):
                base_record = attributes.List[i].Base_Record
                if base_record != file:
                    self.Processsed.add(base_record)
                    self.Nameless[base_record] = file

    def resolve_MFT_name_worker(self, file: int, record: File_Record) -> str:
        if name := self.Names.get(file):
            return name

        self.Processsed.add(file)
        attribute_list = None
        filename = None
        for attr in record.Attributes:
            if isinstance(attr, FileName) and attr.Name_Space != "DOS":
                filename = attr
            elif isinstance(attr, Attribute_List):
                attribute_list = attr

        if not filename:
            return self.process_attribute_list(file, attribute_list)

        if (base_record := record.Header.Base_Record) and base_record != file:
            self.Nameless[base_record] = file

        self.find_nameless_files(file, attribute_list)
        return self.get_file_name(file, filename)

    def process_attribute_list(self, base_file: int, attributes: Attribute_List) -> str:
        files = set()
        nameless = set()
        for i in range(attributes.Count):
            attr = attributes.List[i]
            base_record = attr.Base_Record
            self.Processsed.add(base_record)
            nameless.add(base_record)
            if attr.Type == 48 and base_record != base_file:
                files.add(base_record)

        return self.process_attribute_list_worker(base_file, files, nameless)

    def process_attribute_list_worker(
        self, base_file: int, files: list, nameless: list
    ) -> str:
        filename = None
        for file in files:
            record = self.load_file_record(file)
            for attr in record.Attributes:
                if isinstance(attr, FileName) and attr.Name_Space != "DOS":
                    filename = attr
                    break
            if filename:
                break

        name = self.get_file_name(file, filename)
        self.Nameless[base_file] = file
        nameless.remove(file)
        for f in nameless:
            self.Nameless[f] = file

        return name

    def get_file_name(self, file: int, filename: FileName) -> str:
        parent_file = filename.Parent_Record
        parent_name = self.Names.get(parent_file)
        if not parent_name:
            parent_record = self.load_file_record(parent_file)
            parent_name = self.resolve_MFT_name_worker(parent_file, parent_record)

        self.Names[file] = name = f"{parent_name}/{filename.File_Name}"
        return name

    def resolve_MFT_name(self, file: int, record: File_Record) -> None:
        hardlinks = record.Header.HardLinks
        if 12 <= file <= 23 and not hardlinks:
            self.Unused.add(file)
            return

        base_record = record.Header.Base_Record
        if base_record and base_record in self.Names:
            self.Nameless[file] = base_record

        elif name_record := self.Nameless.get(base_record):
            self.Nameless[file] = name_record

        elif not hardlinks:
            self.Nameless[file] = base_record

        else:
            self.resolve_MFT_name_worker(file, record)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import json
    from pathlib import Path

    partition = Partition("D")
    partition.resolve_MFT_names()
    Path("C:/Users/Xeni/Desktop/MFT_Filenames.json").write_text(
        json.dumps(partition.Names, indent=4, ensure_ascii=False, sort_keys=True),
        encoding="utf8",
    )
    Path("C:/Users/Xeni/Desktop/MFT_Nameless.json").write_text(
        json.dumps(partition.Nameless, indent=4, ensure_ascii=False, sort_keys=True),
        encoding="utf8",
    )
    Path("C:/Users/Xeni/Desktop/MFT_Unused.json").write_text(
        json.dumps(
            sorted(partition.Unused), indent=4, ensure_ascii=False, sort_keys=True
        ),
        encoding="utf8",
    )
```

I won't show you the full output as it is extremely large, `MFT_Filenames.json` is 145MiB 519KiB 213B in size.

Here is a small sample of it:

```
{
    "0": "./$MFT",
    "1": "./$MFTMirr",
    "2": "./$LogFile",
    "3": "./$Volume",
    "4": "./$AttrDef",
    "5": ".",
    "6": "./$Bitmap",
    "7": "./$Boot",
    "8": "./$BadClus",
    "9": "./$Secure",
    "10": "./$UpCase",
    "11": "./$Extend",
    "17": "./System Volume Information/Chkdsk",
    "18": "./System Volume Information/Chkdsk/Chkdsk20220712054831.log",
    "19": "./System Volume Information/Chkdsk/Chkdsk20230315021852.log",
    "20": "./System Volume Information/Chkdsk/Chkdsk20240118192717.log",
    "24": "./$Extend/$Quota",
    "25": "./$Extend/$ObjId",
    "26": "./$Extend/$Reparse",
    "27": "./$Extend/$RmMetadata",
    "28": "./$Extend/$RmMetadata/$Repair",
    "29": "./$Extend/$Deleted",
    "30": "./$Extend/$RmMetadata/$TxfLog",
    "31": "./$Extend/$RmMetadata/$Txf",
    "32": "./$Extend/$RmMetadata/$TxfLog/$Tops",
    "33": "./$Extend/$RmMetadata/$TxfLog/$TxfLog.blf",
    "34": "./$Extend/$RmMetadata/$TxfLog/$TxfLogContainer00000000000000000001",
    "35": "./$Extend/$RmMetadata/$TxfLog/$TxfLogContainer00000000000000000002",
    "36": "./System Volume Information",
    "37": "./System Volume Information/WPSettings.dat",
    "38": "./CliExec",
    "39": "./images/Art",
    "40": "./CliExec/devcon.exe",
    "41": "./CliExec/errorLookup.exe",
    "42": "./Install/Programming/Ada/gnat-2021-20210519-x86_64-windows64-bin.exe",
    "43": "./CliExec/gethost.exe",
    "44": "./CliExec/gt.c",
    "45": "./CliExec/IEDriverServer.exe",
    "46": "./CliExec/msedgedriver.exe",
    "47": "./CliExec/proxy.exe",
    "48": "./CliExec/sfk.exe",
    "49": "./CliExec/tcping.exe",
    "50": "./CliExec/tracetcp.exe",
    "51": "./downloads",
    "52": "./tor",
    "53": "./images/MyCreations/2021-04-14T155801 EC8ADF060956E5DE410EC4A1B9111E4F294EEA711A1410D15CC1B08FF60DE34A.png",
    "54": "./Winpy.txt",
    "55": "./Programs/FOMM",
    "56": "./downloads/TTW/FO3/Fallout.new.vegas.ultimate.edition.GOG/setup_fallout_new_vegas_1.4.0.525_(12010).exe",
    "57": "./Links/Utilities/Hex",
    "58": "./iso/deepin-desktop-community-1010-amd64.iso",
    "59": "./downloads/expressvpn_windows_12.46.0.42_release.exe",
    "60": "./Programs/Mydm/DLBT.dht",
    "61": "./MyScript/SysEnv.csv",
    "62": "./iso/FreeBSD-12.2-RELEASE-amd64-dvd1.iso",
    "63": "./Programs/loot_0.17.0-0-g36fedfe_0.17.0/GPUCache"
}
```

I have noticed that the program takes several minutes to complete execution.

How can I make the program faster?

---

### ***Update***

In case anyone is interested in what exactly do I use this program's output for, here is the code that finds what all the file records in [Chkdsk20240118192717.log](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1KO8NzUkLOKohP-uYVskdrrusSDc_GgTK/view?usp=sharing) actually point to, and organize them in a tree structure.

You need [MFT_Unused.json](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1ljcsHLvet0HbFqVo1tdgYEh9EWsZcWGk/view?usp=sharing), [MFT_NAMELESS.json](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1zwrN9m__EQG6xCesKaMzwEzvJxZ9shFi/view?usp=sharing) and [MFT_FILENAMES.json](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1ekadPRa-7rvt4edKE_xbYqouJ6KkMXlh/view?usp=sharing) to get the same results as mine, all files are uploaded to Google drive.

```
import json
import re
from pathlib import Path

FILE_NAMES = {
    int(k): v
    for k, v in json.loads(
        Path("C:/Users/Xeni/Desktop/MFT_Filenames.json").read_text(encoding="utf8")
    ).items()
}
NAMELESS = {
    int(k): v
    for k, v in json.loads(
        Path("C:/Users/Xeni/Desktop/MFT_Nameless.json").read_text()
    ).items()
}
UNUSED = set(
    map(int, json.loads(Path("C:/Users/Xeni/Desktop/MFT_Unused.json").read_text()))
)

LOG = (
    Path("D:/System Volume Information/Chkdsk/Chkdsk20240118192717.log")
    .read_text(encoding="utf-16-le")
    .splitlines()
)

STAGE_1 = []
STAGE_2 = []
STAGE_3 = []
buffer = []

stage = 0
skip = False
for line in LOG:
    if line := line.strip():
        if line.startswith("Stage 1"):
            stage += 1
            continue

        if skip:
            if not line.startswith("Stage 2"):
                continue
            stage += 1
            skip = False
        else:
            if line.endswith("file records processed."):
                skip = True
                STAGE_1.append(buffer)
                buffer = []
                continue

            if stage == 1:
                if line.startswith(("Attribute", "Cleaning", "Unable")) and buffer:
                    STAGE_1.append(buffer)
                    buffer = []

                buffer.append(line)

        if line.startswith("Stage 3"):
            stage += 1

        if stage == 2:
            STAGE_2.append(line)

        elif stage == 3:
            STAGE_3.append(line)


STAGE_1_PROCESSED = {}
PROCESSED = set()


def process(fileno: int, table: dict) -> None:
    if fileno in UNUSED or fileno in PROCESSED:
        return

    PROCESSED.add(fileno)
    if basefile := NAMELESS.get(fileno):
        name = FILE_NAMES[basefile]
    else:
        name = FILE_NAMES[fileno]

    fields = name.split("/")
    dic = table
    for field in fields:
        dic = dic.setdefault(field, {})


for e in STAGE_1:
    if re.match(
        "^Attribute record of type 0x[\da-fA-F]+ and instance tag 0x[\da-fA-F]+ is cross linked$",
        e[0],
    ):
        file = re.match("^in file 0x([\da-fA-F]+) is already in use\.$", e[3])
    elif re.match(
        "Unable to locate attribute with instance tag 0x[\dA-F]+ and segment", e[0]
    ):
        file = re.match("^from file record segment 0x([\da-fA-F]+)\.$", e[3])
    else:
        file = re.match("^Cleaning up instance tags for file 0x([\da-fA-F]+)\.$", e[0])

    process(int(file.groups()[0], 16), STAGE_1_PROCESSED)

Path("C:/Users/Xeni/Desktop/Chkdsk-STAGE1-Processed.json").write_text(
    json.dumps(STAGE_1_PROCESSED, indent=4, ensure_ascii=False), encoding="utf8"
)

STAGE_2_PROCESSED = {}

for e in STAGE_2:
    if file := re.search("(?<=file )((0x)?[\da-fA-F]+)", e):
        process(int(file.group(), 16), STAGE_2_PROCESSED)

Path("C:/Users/Xeni/Desktop/Chkdsk-STAGE2-Processed.json").write_text(
    json.dumps(STAGE_2_PROCESSED, indent=4, ensure_ascii=False), encoding="utf8"
)


STAGE_3_PROCESSED = {}
for e in STAGE_3:
    if file := re.match("^Inserting data attribute into file ([\da-fA-F]+)\.$", e):
        process(int(file.groups()[0], 16), STAGE_3_PROCESSED)


Path("C:/Users/Xeni/Desktop/Chkdsk-STAGE3-Processed.json").write_text(
    json.dumps(STAGE_3_PROCESSED, indent=4, ensure_ascii=False), encoding="utf8"
)
```

Run the code and see what the output is. I think you probably can replace the file paths yourself.

I am checking the integrity of the files referred to in the output.
I just discovered that it is extremely easy to verify that these files are indeed corrupt, because they all are 0 bytes in size, their data attributes are deleted...

Comment: You'll soon run up against the inherent limits of Python. What's the actual application? How much of the output do you truly need? Is inline filtering possible - if so, what is your predicate? C/C++ will do better.

Comment: Re: patcher -- We don't like inheritance mixins?

Comment: @Reinderien Why? Python is very much integrated with *nix operating systems and has pretty good filesystem support. Would it be something NTFS-specific they'd run into?

Comment: Certainly Python is well-integrated; that's not what I'm worried about, but rather the performance penalties paid by CPU-bound Python code. That said, OP has not shown profiling results so it's unclear whether this is CPU-bound or IO-bound.

Comment: I am considering starting a 50 reputation bounty for this question, as this question has received 5 upvotes I won't have net loss, but the last time I started a bounty no one posted an answer, so I wasted the reputation. If anyone is interested in the bounty, just post a comment here to let me know.